# Need assistance with exiting this while loop that is contained within a string in java

Tags: java

I have tried putting two user inputs but can't seem to find a way to exit this loop after conducting a binary search to find an item in an array list. I need this to return a string to use the input as the name for my game. This is what I have got so far:

```
public String chooseBird() { //bird chosen will be depending on user input and binary search
    String chosenBird = "";

    String[] tempArr = new String[myBirdList.size()];//breks birds into array list string
    tempArr = myBirdList.toArray(tempArr);
    String selectBird ;
    System.out.println("Enter the bird you wish to use for the adventure: ");
    Scanner mySearch = new Scanner(System.in); //assign my search as 
    selectBird = mySearch.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Hit 'begin' to start or 'end' to stop");
    Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String myValue = "";
    int result = binarySearch(tempArr, selectBird);

    do{
        myValue = myInput.nextLine();
        if (result == -1) {
            System.out.println("We could not find this bird, please enter a bird from the list above");
        } 
        else {
            chosenBird = selectBird; //chosenBird is assigned as the return value to assign as the game name
            System.out.println("\n" + selectBird + " was chosen and found at index " + result); //bird has been found in the list and selected for the adventure
        }
    } while (!myValue.contains("end") || result != -1); //keep prompting for input until we find a bird, bird found when result does not = -1

    return chosenBird;
}
```

Comment: I cannot see you make use of `myValue` and update `result` within the loop body. Did you forget to actually do the search?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `break` statement for this:

```
chosenBird = selectBird; //chosenBird is assigned as the return value to assign as the game name
System.out.println("\n" + selectBird + " was chosen and found at index " + result); //bird has been found in the list and selected for the adventure
break;
```

Comment: still not working.. could it be something to do with being a string instead of a void?

Comment: obviously if you are returning a String it would be String not void